# set multiple column values for multiple rows with loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Dataframe:

> ```
>      A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K
> 0    .  .  .  .  .  .  X  L  .  .  .
> 1    .  .  .  .  .  .  X  A  .  .  .
> .
> .
> .
> 300  .  .  .  .  .  .  X  R  .  .  .
> 301  .  .  .  .  .  . nan R  .  .  .
> 302  .  .  .  .  .  .  X  R  .  .  .
> 303  .  .  .  .  .  . nan R  .  .  .
> ```

I am trying to change columns G and I to U if H = R.
Expected output:

> ```
>      A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K
> 0    .  .  .  .  .  .  X  L  .  .  .
> 1    .  .  .  .  .  .  X  A  .  .  .
> .
> .
> .
> 300  .  .  .  .  .  .  U  R  U  .  .
> 301  .  .  .  .  .  .  U  R  U  .  .
> 302  .  .  .  .  .  .  U  R  U  .  .
> 303  .  .  .  .  .  .  U  R  U  .  .
> ```

Is there a way to pass multiple columns to the loc here instead of doing this twice or having to loop twice like this which looks non-pythonic:

df.loc[df['H'] == 'R', 'G'] = 'U'

df.loc[df['H'] == 'R', 'I'] = 'U'

I thought this would be trivial but can't find any clear solution.

Comment: You should be able to do `df.loc[df['H'] == 'R', ['G','I']] = 'U'`, I believe.

Comment: Thanks !  Would it possible to have something that filters for H=R and then sets G to U and I to M for example in a single liner ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be quicker to just try it?  I believe pandas will do broadcast, so `df.loc[df['H'] == 'R', ['G','I']] = ['U','M']` should work.  However, at what point does this become unmaintainable, whereas the individual assignment is easily grasped?  This is almost certainly not your critical performance point.

Comment: Definetly not the performance but it was more of a readability/writing in a pythonic way. copy pasting lines just felt wrong and I didn't know where to start, all examples i found only used a single column/value.

Comment: I love a good one-liner, but I've also learned through my long career that focusing on tricky code leads to one being hated by the programmers that follow...

Comment: Duly Noted Tim. I am only just starting in this path and taking all the tips and best practices advice I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tim already mentioned you can proceed like the following :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': ['.']*304,
    'B': ['.']*304,
    'C': ['.']*304,
    'D': ['.']*304,
    'E': ['.']*304,
    'F': ['.']*304,
    'G': ['.']*301 + ['nan', 'X', 'nan'],
    'H': ['L', 'A'] + ['R']*301,
    'I': ['.']*304,
    'J': ['.']*304,
    'K': ['.']*304
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Modify 'G' and 'I' columns where 'H' is 'R'
df.loc[df['H'] == 'R', ['G', 'I']] = 'U'

print(df)
```

If you want to get for H=R and then sets G to U and I to M for example in a single liner :

```
df.loc[df['H'] == 'R', ['G', 'I']] = df.loc[df['H'] == 'R'].assign(G='U', I='M')[['G', 'I']]
```